# how can I show this integral diverges?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, analysis, gamma-function

I want to show $E(T_a)=\infty$

$$E(T_a)=\int_0^{\infty}{{x|a|}\over\sqrt{2\pi}}x^{-3/2}e^{-a^2/x}dx$$

to show this I need to show this integral diverges.

I know gamma function that

$$\Gamma (\alpha)=\int_0^\infty x^{\alpha -1}e^{-x}dx$$

By benefit from gamma function, how can I show this integral diverges ?

Thank you for helping

Comment: Try $u=-a^2/x$ in the integral, and see what you get.

Comment: If it diverges it is because of its behavior near $x=0$, it converges on $[1,\infty)$.

Comment: @GregoryGrant No, it's just the opposite. Convergence at $0$ is clear, and the integral over $[1,\infty)$ diverges.

Comment: @zhw. Doesn't it behave like $\frac{1}{e^x\sqrt{x}}$?  I'm pretty sure that converges on $[1,\infty)$.

Comment: No, see my answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As suggested by mickep, making the change of variable 
$$u:=a^2/x, \qquad |a|x^{-1/2}=u^{1/2}, \qquad dx=-\frac{a^2}{u^2}du 
$$  gives
$$\begin{align}
\int_0^{\infty}{{x|a|}\over\sqrt{2\pi}}x^{-3/2}e^{-a^2/x}dx&={{|a|}\over\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_0^{\infty}x^{-1/2}e^{-a^2/x}dx\\\\
&={{1}\over\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_0^{\infty}\frac1{u^{3/2}}e^{-u}\:du\\\\
&\geq{{1}\over\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_0^{\ln 2}\frac1{u^{3/2}}\times\frac12\:du\\\\
&\geq{{1}\over\sqrt{2\pi}}\left[-\frac1{\sqrt{u}}\right]_0^{\ln 2}\\\\
&\geq +\infty
\end{align}
$$ and your integral is **divergent**.

Answer (score 3):

Since $e^{-a^2/x} \to 1$ at $\infty,$ we have $e^{-a^2/x} > 1/2$ for large $x.$ It follows that the integrand is on the order of $1/\sqrt x$  for large $x.$ Since $\int_b^\infty (1/\sqrt x)\,dx = \infty$ for all $b>0,$ the integral diverges.